# Does an expression enumerate parameters when executed in LINQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a method that returns an `IQueryable` using LINQ

```
 return eventFacade.GetNewBuildingEvents()
                .Where(EventPredicates.IsBuildingOwner(
                       memberFacade.GetFriendsAndColleagues(m).Select(y => y.Id))
        )
```

`GetFriendsAndColleagues(m).Select(y => y.Id)` returns an IEnumerable

```
        public static Expression<Func<Event, bool>> IsBuildingOwner(IEnumerable<int> friendids)
    {
        return
            x =>
                x.Building.BuildingMembers.Where(k => k.Type == MemberType.Owner)
                    .Any(p => friendids.Contains(p.Member.Id));
    }
```

I am still learning LINQ and C# in general. I know both `IQueryable` and `IEnumerable` defer execution, and I know filtering with an `IQueryable` takes place in the databsae while `IEnumerable` takes place in memory.

I also know that in instances where one is iterating over a collection it is best to enumerate the collection so that each iteration doesn't make a call to the database.

So when my final query is executed does the `IEnumerable` passed into my expression get enumerated once and then used to compare each item returned by `GetNewBuildingEvents()`

or

Does it make a call to the database on each comparison to get the list?

Comment: What is the implementation and return type of `GetNewBuildingEvents`? what is the IQueryable provider? anyway, I believe or it's LINQ-to-entities or the IQueryable will throw an exception.

Comment: I use .AsEnumerable() on the query and transform it into another object later in the method. The query as written above compiles and runs fine

Comment: You're asking specifically about Linq to SQL / DB right? Because AFAIK you can use both IQueryable and IEnumerable for both LINQ to Objects as well as Linq to DB. What actually runs in the end depends on the LINQ provider.

Comment: @Vivek It's linq-to-entites up until the end of this query at which point I use `AsEnumerable` and go to linq-to-objects.

Comment: Just attach a profiler to your SQL and see the exact queries being sent. If you (and/or your DB admins) are satisfied with the resulting queries then live with them. If not, you could start thinking about optimizing them.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov thanks for the suggestion. Our database only has a few entries for this table right now(Still building the application!) so I wouldn't see much of a difference but I will definitely be using this approach once we get some real data.

Comment: @MattFoxxDuncan The point is to look at the SQL query generated from this C# code, not so much to see how long it runs.  That will help you determine what operations are successfully mapped to SQL, and what is either inefficiently mapped to SQL or not mapped to SQL at all and done on the client side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to know how many times it's iterate just run that code on a sequence that performs some observable side effect when it's iterated so that you can see how many times it happens.

You can use the following helper method to wrap any sequence into one that will write out to the console the each time it's iterated.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> NoisyWrapper<T>(IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Rabble rabble rabble!!!");
    foreach (var item in source)
        yield return item;
}
```

So that solves the problem in the general case.

In the specific case, the sequence should only be iterated once.  You're creating an expression that's compiled into a DB query and executed on the DB end.  Using `Contains` from an `IEnumerable` with most SQL-based query providers in the appropriate context (which yours is) will be translated into an `IN` clause in SQL.  The `IEnumerable` will need to be iterated once to supply the values for the `IN` clause, and it shouldn't need to be iterated more than once.

Comment: fantastic! thank you, this is just the explanation I was looking for.